# Regular Expression with php Error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have the following html structure :

```
<div data-provincia="mi" data-nazione="it" ecc...
```

I'm trying to take "mi" with preg_match function.
This is my code :

```
$pattern = '/data-provincia=*"[a-zA-Z]*"/';
preg_match($pattern,$element,$provincia);
```

I think that the code is right but it doesn't match with anything.
Where i'm wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: works ok for me [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gpkz-e1vf)

Comment: Simple: don't. Try a [parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the quantifier + (1 or more) next to the character class between brackets, and remove the first star. Also added a subtpattern for you to get exactly the part you want. Give it a try :

```
$pattern = '/data-provincia="([a-zA-Z]+)"/';
preg_match($pattern,$element,$provincia);
echo $provincia[1];
```

Comment: It also return me a empty array.

Comment: I updated my answer (move the + inside the subpattern), please try again.

Comment: Still don't work. The regex is right (also mine works okay) but it return me and empty array.

Comment: Sorry, it works, Thank you.

Comment: yw, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$element = '<div data-provincia="mi" data-nazione="it" ecc...>';
$pattern = '/<div[^>]*data-provincia=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>/';
preg_match($pattern,$element,$provincia);
print_r($provincia[1]);
```

Comment: Show your full code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment, for this simple attribute you can use the following regex:

```
$regex = '/data-provincia="([^"]*)/i';
preg_match($regex,$element,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Basically match everything except a double quote as many times as possible (or none). But please at least consider using a [Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for this task, regular expressions were not meant to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine for me

```
$element = '<div data-provincia="mi" data-nazione="it"></div>';
$pattern = '/data-provincia=*"[a-zA-Z]*"/';
$matches= array();
preg_match($pattern,$element, $matches);
if (!empty($matches)) {
    foreach ($matches as $eachOne) {
        //code to remove unwanted
        $text = trim(preg_replace('/^data-provincia\=/', '', $eachOne), '""');
        echo " $eachOne; $text";
    }

}
```